# Can someone help in computing curvature tensor of a surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I have a problem, I've been thinking about all day. Came across this while browsing some lecture notes online. 
So, I have a surface in space say, described as $z= f(x,y)$ and I want to find it's sectional curvature.

I think we can do this by first finding Riemannian-metric $(g_{ij})$ of this manifold  described by this surface, then find christoffel's symbols, from there one can find local expression for curvature tensor, which is sufficient to find sectional curvature.

I think that's it but with some surfaces this is taking just so much time to compute, and I don't think is the best method around. Can someone here help me figure out an alternate (better) way to do this?

Thanks and Cheers!

Comment: This is a good question that I don't have much time to write up an answer for, but I believe the best way is to use classical differential geometry of surfaces. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/357563/2002) for the insights. Essentially, your computation will end up with finding the Gaussian curvature.

Comment: I would post an answer in the form of an algorithm, but first I wish to know how fast you want it to be? Because you know that sometimes keeping some computations in real-time (roughly speaking under 1 s) would require a lot of additional precautions. Do you want the result in the form of symbolic formula ? or you are dealing with numerical computations?

Comment: @Arvin: Symbolic formula works for me, as long as it's not too complicated to derive the numerical value of curvature from that.

Comment: @Yuri: I'm going through the solution you suggested, I'll post with my version of the solution soon. I hope you can check if it's correct!

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{R^3}$ Monge form surface  $z= f(x,y)$ has sectional curvature same as the Gaussian curvature K. Using Classical approach like with Christoffel symbols ( Diff Geom texts Barret O'Neill, DJ Struik, Ted Shifrin .. ) and with notation

$$ r = f_{xx}, t= f_{yy} , s=  f_{xy}, p= f_x, q= f_y ; $$

we obtain

$$ K= \frac{(rt-s^2)}{(1+p^2+q^2)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I have come to this solution. I hope it's correct

In case of a surface embedded in $\mathbb{R^3}$, say described as $z= f(x,y)$ it's sectional curvature is the same as it's Gaussian curvature. And we know that the latter is given by 
$$ K = \frac{f_{xx} f_{yy} - (f_{xy})^2 }{(1+(f_x)^2 +(f_y)^2)^2}$$

Comment: The formula that you have written here is wrong! The correct one would be $(f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2)/ (1+(f_x)^2+(f_y)^2)^2$. In order to prove it, its best if you resort to classical differential geometry. Assuming your parameterization map is denoted by $\textbf{X}$, compute the $\mathbf{X}_x$ and $\mathbf{X}_{y}$ and from there obtain the normal to the surface $N_p$ at point $p$ of your surface. Then the Gaussian curvature by definition will be the determinant of $dN_p$. You might find "Brioschi formula" helpful as well for the proof.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative strategy for computing the Gaussian curvature of a surface equipped with a Riemannian metric is using Cartan's moving frames. Namely, if $(E_1,E_2)$ is a frame defined on an open subset of the surface and $(\theta^1,\theta^2)$ is the dual coframe, one defines the *connection $1$-forms* $\omega^i_{~j}$ by the relations $\nabla_XE_j = \sum_i \omega^i_{~j}(X)E_j$. If $(E_1,E_2)$ is an orthonormal frame, one can show that ${\rm d}\omega^1_{~2} = K\,\theta^1\wedge \theta^2$.

To compute $\omega^i_{~j}$ in concrete cases, one uses the *structure equations* ${\rm d}\theta^i = \sum_j\theta^j \wedge \omega^i_{~j}$ and the metric compatibility $\omega_{ij}+\omega_{ji} = {\rm d}g_{ij}$, where $(g_{ij})$ are the components of the metric with respect to the frame $(E_1,E_2)$ and $\omega_{ij}$ is obtained by lowering $i$ in $\omega^i_{~j}$ using the metric, that is, $\omega_{ij} = \sum_kg_{ik}\omega^k_{~j}$. You can see proofs that everything works [in these notes](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/cartan_formalism.pdf).

In the particular example for graphs, these computations (and all others, to be honest) are a bit more complicated, because the coordinate vector fields associated to the Monge chart are not orthogonal (so Gram-Schmidt is required if one wants to employ moving frames).